# Using c# to control access to an exe

Tags: c#, exe

I've been cracking my head trying to figure out how to control who opens an exe (example; notepad) from my C# GUI. So the C# GUI will be published as an executable and a button on the GUI can be used to open that exe. once the exe form is closed it can't be opened unless it via the GUI that I'll be writing code for.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem? or if it's even possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is this for? Sounds annoying

Comment: Do you mean you want to start a program using C#??

Comment: It's a personal project I'm working on. @Mr.香港人 yes i want to start a program only from my C# exe.

Comment: something like an app lock. This exe cant be opened unless it's through my C# GUI.

Comment: Is this program you are starting under your control (can you modify it)? the options to limit the launching of a 3rd party exe are much fewer than the options you have if you can modify the `static void Main(string[] args)` of the program you are starting.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes, the C# GUI is implemented by myself. I just need to add a button that invokes an exe when pushed. I know this is likely to get complicated but i just need directions on where to start. Thanks

Comment: I did not ask if the GUI app is written by you, I wanted to know is the EXE the GUI is launching written by you.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain no. Basically,  It can be any exe on my computer

Answer (score 0):

If you control the EXE that is being launched, you can have it check its "parent process" to see if it's your GUI executable.  This isn't the most secure thing in the world....but might do for your needs.

A quick Bing search turned up this link: http://www.rhyous.com/2010/04/30/how-to-get-the-parent-process-that-launched-a-c-application/